How to make quantity increase / decrease with minimal_quantity in Prestashop shopping cart
i would use for all Products the {$product.minimal_quantity} query to increase / decrease the amount of products in the Prestashop Cart.
I use this function already in the Product Details Site with
data-step="{$product.minimal_quantity}"

and
value="{if in_array( $product->id, array(xxx,xxx,xxx)) }
{$product.minimal_quantity}{else}{$product.quantity_wanted}{/if}"

That works fine. For example, if the minimal quantity 10, then gives me 10,20,30...steps.
I try the same function in the cart site. There visually give me the same function if i add
data-step="{$product.minimal_quantity}"
but increase the product value just with 1 not with 10.
How can i modify the cart section to add the Function to increase the quantity of product = minimal_quantity? Version is 1.8
Thanks for any help

Could you please add more details ? What theme are you using ?
What file are you modifying for Cart page ? Can you paste the modifications made in this file ?

Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?
